# How using common script in components with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a component (see below) when I try to use a method from an javascript file. But not work, what is the right way to do it ?

```
<template>
  <div id="test"></div>
</template>

<script>
import myShared from '../shared.js'

export default {
  methods: {
    postPost() {
      myShared.displayMessage();
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

I'd like then the method `displayMessage` will be usable in each component from this script :

```
export default {  
  methods: {
     displayMessage: function () {
        console.log('Test')
     }
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: You can look at the documentation for mixins: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Comment: That's work with Vue CLI ? no special thinks to do ?

Comment: yes, nothing special. If you write the mixin in a separate file, you just need to import it where you want to use.

Comment: Use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)

Comment: Have you tried importing instead in the main.js?

Answer (score -1):

1. You can use mixins (but it's probably will deprecate in vue.js 3)
2. You can create any `helper.js` where you will export functions.